# Accessibility service disabled automatically

Tags: android, android-studio, service, accessibilityservice

I am working with accessibility service and my service always auto disabled when I run the code from my android studio. But when I exit the app and launch again from my phone it works fine.

I googled it but couldn't find a worthwhile answer

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.